# Is 'Shut down computer when finished' during Avidemux encoding stage useful?

Tags: shutdown, video-editing

I get the option to **Shut down computer when finished** during encoding stage of Avidemux. Why would I want to do that?

[image]

Comment: It's sad to have a downvote without a reason. It's not obvious to me, why I deserved this.

Comment: how about I downvoted it because because [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/), and I can't see this as an actual problem you're facing.

Comment: @xeno Considering that that post was published *after* your down-vote, is it what you had in mind?

Comment: I think my generalized thought was that, this really is not a problem. But it's not offtopic either... which is why it wasn't closed. In all fairness this was me as a person, not as a moderator, saying I don't like this question and I don't think it's a good one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe because you're encoding is going to take hours after you leave and you don't really want to keep the computer running when you're not using it to save power.